# Why can't install scrapy on my debian8?

Tags: python, scrapy

```
aptitude search  packaging
i   packaging-dev                                                                  - convenient tools to develop packages
```

Now to install  packaging-dev

```
debian8@hwy:~$ sudo apt-get install  packaging-dev
debian8@hwy:~$ sudo aptitude search cryptography

i A python-cryptography                                                            - Python library exposing cryptographic recipes and primitives (Python 2)                 
p   python-cryptography-doc                                                        - Python library exposing cryptographic recipes and primitives (documentation)            
p   python-cryptography-vectors                                                    - Test vectors for python-cryptography (Python 2)                                         
p   python3-cryptography                                                           - Python library exposing cryptographic recipes and primitives (Python 3)                 
p   python3-cryptography-vectors                                                   - Test vectors for python-cryptography (Python 3)
```

Now to install python-cryptography

```
debian8@hwy:~$ sudo apt-get install python-cryptography

pip3 install scrapy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 70, in <module>
    import packaging.version
ImportError: No module named 'packaging'
```

pakaging is already installed ,why it can't be imported?

Comment: Is there a reason for using aptitude and not pip?

Answer (score 0):

```
Collecting scrapy
  Downloading Scrapy-1.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (239kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 245kB 1.1MB/s 
Collecting PyDispatcher>=2.0.5 (from scrapy)
  Downloading PyDispatcher-2.0.5.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: Twisted>=13.1.0 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: lxml in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: service-identity in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied: pyOpenSSL in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from scrapy)
Collecting w3lib>=1.15.0 (from scrapy)
  Downloading w3lib-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting parsel>=0.9.5 (from scrapy)
  Downloading parsel-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting cssselect>=0.9 (from scrapy)
  Downloading cssselect-1.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5.2 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from scrapy)
Collecting queuelib (from scrapy)
  Downloading queuelib-1.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: cryptography>=0.7 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from pyOpenSSL->scrapy)
Installing collected packages: PyDispatcher, w3lib, cssselect, parsel, queuelib, scrapy
  Running setup.py install for PyDispatcher ... done
Successfully installed PyDispatcher-2.0.5 cssselect-1.0.1 parsel-1.1.0 queuelib-1.4.2 scrapy-1.3.0 w3lib-1.16.0
```

i am able to install using `sudo pip install scrapy`

Answer (score 0):

To install python3.6 by compiling,and

```
pip3.6 install scrapy
```

[to sovle issues relate dto install srapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42156824/why-cant-reinstall-python3-4-or-python3/42173938#42173938)
[to sovle issues relate dto install srapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42171523/how-to-fix-the-broken-package-managerhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/42171523/how-to-fix-the-broken-package-manager)